# Expose child properties of user control directly as property of user control

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Without breaking MVVM, is there a way to expose some properties of a child control in a user control so that the window or other user control that utilizes it can access these properties directly?

For instance I have a user control that has a listview set up with gridviewcolumns, headers, and is bound to a view model. But the list view in the user control has selected item properties and such that I'd like to expose to the host without having to do something like usercontrol.customListView.property. Or is that how I should do it? I'd like to go just usercontrol.property, omitting customListView. Perhap I should just create properties in the user controls code behind that return the list view controls properties that I want attached directly to the user control?

I feel like that latter option doesn't really break MVVM since they are exposed for the host to interact with, not really related to the view itself. Any suggested would be appreciated.

EDIT: In fact, I'd really like to have a SelectedItem property directly on the user control that is not ListViewItem or object, but actually of the datatype contained that doe like:

```
public MyDataType SelectedItem {
    get {
        return customListView.SelectedItem as MyDataType;
    }
}
```

Would that be permissible in MVVM? Because I don't see how I could have that in the ViewModel, seems like it would have to be in the partial class code behind.

Comment: Just add DepandencyProperty on your control and bind to it / rebind it (`Binding RelativeSource{FindAncestor}`) on child control (btw and maybe OT, .columns on WPF datagrid is not bindable). Cant see any problem with MVVM - lets say ComboBox is using others controls and you dont have any problem to use it in MVVM :)

Comment: This question has nothing to do with MVVM.

Comment: "I have a user control that has a listview set up with gridviewcolumns, headers, **and is bound to a view model.**" Yep, that's why you're having issues.  You shouldn't have ANY ViewModels inside your UserControl.  You should expose properties on the surface for everything you need, then bind your UC child controls to these properties.  If you have to perform UI logic in your UC, use the codebehind.  Don't create a VM designed to be used inside of the UC.  Does a TextBox have a TextBoxViewModel?  No.  Treat your UC like a Control, not a subset of logic.

Comment: @Sheridan Did you read the question? I am using MVVM and wanted to expose some things on the user control. I didn't know if that affected the MVVM aspect of it or if we are supposed to refrain from that in practice, but I just don't see how one would defer that exposure to the view model.

Comment: @Will I understand what you are saying but I think maybe I wasn't clear about intentions. I have a specialized ListView control. with column set up for a specific class (Company). There is some business logic going on with this control that happens in the view model that interacts with a network layer and database. Once this data is fetched and listed, there is what this control is intended to do, view and select a company from the list. This latter aspect is separate from the internal view model.

Comment: Yes I read the question.  Your design is working against you.  From your second clarification it seems as though your UC is too big, if it encompasses another distinct process.  UCs are most effective if small, designed to be a specialized control designed against a part of your overall MVVM design (like a TextBox edits a string, a PersonUserControl might edit a Person model). If you use UCs to encompass huge chunks of UI, you can find yourself in situations as you described in the above comment.

Comment: @Will Ah. Well given your input I guess I should have it just be a CompanyListView, and specialize it for the Company data type and then expose my SelectedItem and SelectionChanged events, and then bind this business logic where applicable externally wherever this control is used? Apologies, I just starting using MVVM and haven't had much practice in how to divide all this up.

Comment: @Will I actually just read another question about user controls where you talk about this and based on that pretty lengthy answer I think I did understand you recent response. Appreciate your input.

Comment: No problems!  I've made these mistakes before.  If you follow these general rules of thumb about UCs: *1. Keep your UserControls focused 2. don't create specialized VMs for them 3. No business logic inside and 4. Put your UI logic in the codebehind* you'll avoid almost all of the pitfalls we have had to claw ourselves out of.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80910/discussion-between-steviesama-and-will).

Comment: @Will Do you know if Prism's BindableBase implements DependencyProperty for usages of SetProperty when a DependencyProperty doesn't exist for the named property?

Comment: Sorry, never used Prism.

Answer (score 3):

This is pretty common task when you want to put something repeated into `UserControl`. The simplest approach to do so is when you are not creating specialized ViewModel for that `UserControl`, but sort of making *custom control* (build with the use of `UserControl` for simplicity). End result may looks like this

```
<UserControl x:Class="SomeNamespace.SomeUserControl" ...>
    ...
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=UserControl}" ...>
</UserControl>
```

.

```
public partial class SomeUserControl : UserControl
{
    // simple dependency property to bind to
    public string Text
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(TextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TextProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Text", typeof(string), typeof(SomeUserControl), new PropertyMetadata());

    // has some complicated logic
    public double Value
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(ValueProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ValueProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ValueProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Value", typeof(double), typeof(SomeUserControl),
        new PropertyMetadata((d, a) => ((SomeUserControl)d).ValueChanged()));
    private void ValueChanged()
    {
        ... // do something complicated here
            // e.g. create complicated dynamic animation
    }

    ...
}
```

Usage will looks like this in containing window

```
<l:SomeUserControl Text="Text" Value="{Binding SomeValue}" ... />
```

As you can see `SomeValue` is bound to `Value` and there is no MVVM violations.

Of course, you can create a proper `ViewModel` if view logic is complicated or required too much bindings and it's rather easier to allow ViewModels to communicate directly (via properties/methods).

Comment: There is custom logic going on with the view itself which happens in the view model. For instance the one I am working on is a listview with various columns of a Company data type.  I extending BindableBase from Prism and typically use SetProperty() to set properties where possible. Do you know if SetProperty auto registers a DependencyProperty on behalf of the class if it is not yet registered? Also I want to expose SelectedItem as the Company type directly and expose a SelectionChanged Event for the Company type.